# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0), json error

Tags: python, flask, deployment

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import joblib

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST','GET'])
def predict():
    model = joblib.load('rf_grid.pkl')
    data = request.get_json()
    prediction = model.predict([[np.array(data['Age'],data['SipSp'],data['Parch'],
                                          data['Fare'],data['Sex_male'],
                                          data['Cabin_Rare'],data['Embarked_S'])]])
    output = prediction[0]

    return jsonify(output)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This is a flask file that I'm running under app.py

```
import requests
import json

url ='http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict'
dictionary = {'Age':50, 'SipSp':1, 'Parch':1,'Fare':150,'Sex_male':1,'Cabin_Rare':0,'Embarked_S':1}

r = requests.post(url, json = dictionary)
print(r.json())
```

This is the file I'm running under requests.py. When I run this file I get the error:json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

How do I get rid of this error and for my requests.py to run?

Comment: Have you checked if `output` is in the correct format? If it's small enough, maybe try printing it?

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your API logic. I have commented core logic portion and returned JSON response. And It it's not giving any error.

```
import numpy as np
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import joblib

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST','GET'])
def predict():
    # model = joblib.load('rf_grid.pkl')
    # data = request.get_json()
    # prediction = model.predict([[np.array(data['Age'],data['SipSp'],data['Parch'],
    #                                       data['Fare'],data['Sex_male'],
    #                                       data['Cabin_Rare'],data['Embarked_S'])]])
    # output = prediction[0]

    output = {"ok": True}

    return jsonify(output)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

If you can please share `rf_grid.pkl` file So, I can help with that.